# MIPS Assembly sll instruction

Tags: assembly, mips, sll

I have a problem with the sll instruction. `sll $t1,$a0,1` with $a0 holds the value 11 would give $t1 the value 16 (I tested it in MARS).

My suggestion for $t1 was 22, becaus a left shift of 11 aka 01011 would give me 10110, what is 22 in decimal. Where did I made a mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: 0x16 is 22. Maybe your mistake is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `sll $t1,$a0,1` with `$a0` holds the value 11 would give `$t1` the value 16 (I tested it in MARS).

You're probably just mixing up decimal and hexadecimal. If you loaded `$a0` with the value 11 like this `li $a0,11` and shifted it one bit to the left you'd indeed get 22 as the result. The register viewer in Mars shows the values in hexadecimal, and 0x16 equals 22.